# DOMDocument works in individual php file but not in Yii2 controller

Tags: php, yii2, domdocument

I am facing a strange issue. I am trying to instantiate DOMDocument class. it works when i do it in independent .php file, but when i try to use it in Yii2, in one of the controller function i get error.

Class 'app\controllers\DOMDocument' not found

This works, executed from .php file not part of Yii2 project:

```
    $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-15");
    if ($xml) { 
        echo gettype($xml);
    }
    exit;
```

I am stuck. Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks

I have tried to instantiate DOMDocument class in Yii2 controller, but getting error. I am expecting it to work, as it is working outside Yii2 project in same setup

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "" before the class. Yii works based on namespaces and in your scenario compiler thinks that this file exists in current namespace with app/controllers while its a global object so we 'll use "" to explain compiler correct source.

```
$xml = new \DOMDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-15");
        if ($xml) {
            echo gettype($xml);
        }
        exit;
```

[Yii2 Reference](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-modules)